# 'KNeighborsClassifier' object is not callable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have a feature set Xtrain with dimensions (n_obs,n_features) and responses ytrain with dim (n_obs) .   I am attempting to use KNN as a classifier.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier()
clf = neigh(n_neighbors = 10)
clf.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
```

I get error message:

---

TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
 22 clf = neigh(n_neighbors = 10)
 23 # Fit best model to data
 24 clf.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

TypeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object is not callable

Not sure what the problem is...any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 10)
clf.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
```

Classifier parameters go inside the constructor. You where trying to create a new object with an already instantiated classifier.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier
clf = neigh(n_neighbors = 10)
clf.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

would also work.